# Service not found after installing using AssemblyInstaller

Tags: .net, service, installation, servicecontroller

**Context**

Windows 2008 64 bit.
I have a .NET service installed that acts as an installer.

**Background**

I'm using this code (credit: Marc Gravell) to install a service:

```
using (var inst = new AssemblyInstaller(typeof(MyNamespace.Program).Assembly, new string[] { })) {
    IDictionary state = new Hashtable();
    inst.UseNewContext = true;
    try {
    if (uninstall) {
        inst.Uninstall(state);
    } else {
        inst.Install(state);
        inst.Commit(state);
    }
    } catch {
    try {
        inst.Rollback(state);
    } catch { }
    throw;
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

All works fine and no exceptions, but right after that, I try to run the following code to start the service just installed:

```
using (var sc = new ServiceController("the service's name"))
{
    sc.Start();
    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
}
```

And I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Service [service name goes here] was not found on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service does not exist as an installed service
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateNames()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_ServiceName()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
   at ... (my code details)
```

I don't understand why, because:

1. The service's name is the exact one as in the `ServiceInstaller` (in
   the `ServiceName` property)
2. The code is executed inside a different service, which runs under
   *Local System* account.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: @TCopple, inside stackoverflow - clearly not. Outside - maybe, I don't remember. But I don't think so, otherwise I would have answered myself here.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the service is stuck in a waiting state and not yet accomplished the full registration, so it can't be recognized as an installed service.
As you do set `UseNewContext` property - does the installation log file ("{Assembly name}.InstallLog") contain any meaningful information?
Also, to check if this is a permissions issue, can you try to verify service existence using

```
sc query <ServiceName>
```

from an administrative command window?

Answer (score 0):

There is an installation log that might help. Look for the `YouServiceName.InstallLog` file in the service's folder.

Adding an Installer for the service could be enough (it was for me). You should:

- Open the Service.cs file in the designer,
- Right click it, and
- Choose the menu-option "Add Installer".

It won't install right out of the box... you need to create the installer class first.

For reference, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922105/install-windows-service-created-in-visual-studio).