# Installing Windows Service in F#: "No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute ..."

Tags: f#, windows-services

I'm attempting to install the Windows Service I have written in F#, but I keep getting the following message when I run `installutil`:

> No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the C:\path\to\service\myservice.exe assembly.

The Windows service installer code is below. Note that both of the things which the error message claims are missing are, in fact, present:

- `ProjectInstaller` is public.
- `ProjectInstaller` is tagged/decorated with `RunInstaller(true)` attribute.

The service installer code:

```
module Project.WindowsService.Installer

open System.Configuration.Install
open System.ComponentModel
open System.ServiceProcess

[<RunInstaller(true)>]
type public ProjectInstaller () as installer =
    inherit Installer()

    // Define the process settings
    let processInstaller =
        new ServiceProcessInstaller(
            Account  = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem,
            Password = null,
            Username = null)

    // Define the service settings
    let serviceInstaller =
        new ServiceInstaller(
            ServiceName = "Project.WindowsService",
            DisplayName = "My Service",
            Description = "Blah. Blah, blah, blah. And, of course, blah.",
            StartType   = ServiceStartMode.Automatic)

    do
        // Define the installers
        [| processInstaller :> Installer
           serviceInstaller :> Installer |]
        |> installer.Installers.AddRange
```

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that putting the `ProjectInstaller` within a module is a problem: For some reason, `installutil` cannot find it.

Changing the module declaration:

```
module Project.WindowsService.Installer
```

... to a namespace declaration fixes everything:

```
namespace Project.WindowsService
```

Comment: It's because that installer class ends up as "nested class" in CLR terminology, and installutil only looks at top-level classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you came to here from a search link then these two other post may be more relevant to you.  In particular the 1st link below.

[Install Windows Service created in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922105/install-windows-service-created-in-visual-studio)

[Unable to install windows service with the help of InstallUtil tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009163/unable-to-install-windows-service-with-the-help-of-installutil-tool)