# How to install Jenkins Master as windows service?

Tags: jenkins

i'm trying to install Jenkins Master as Windows Service, but the **access** is denied.

---

> FATAL - WMI Operation failure: AccessDenied

---

I've install Jenkins Master with the java -jar command.

---

```
java -jar C:\Jenkins\jenkins.war
```

---

I'm using Windows 10. Can someone help me ? Thx.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500231/installing-jenkins-slave-as-service-on-win8-1-and-win10/37147085?noredirect=1#comment62929396_37147085

Comment: Its not a slave, but a master

Answer (score 0):

I've used the jenkins.msi and It worked !